# .replace() function error

Tags: javascript

I am using the following function to replace `'` in a string with

```
''
```

for ex

```
yourstring= "uncle Tom's cabin";
var crucial = yourstring.replace(/'/g, "''");
```

This does not work and I am not sure why!

Comment: Notwithstanding the space in `your string`, seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/wPnxv/

Comment: @alex If that last edit in which you corrected your code was in response to the comments or answers, then you shouldn't have changed it. Keep everything the way it was so that if users come on to this question, they would know what the problem was with your code.

Comment: As JaredFarrish's code shows it works. What do you mean by "not work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works, you only misspelled "your string" variable.

```
yourstring= "uncle Tom's cabin";
var crucial = yourstring.replace(/'/g, "''");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  var yourstring = "uncle Tom's cabin";
  var crucial = yourstring.replace("'","''");
```

This will only replace one `'`